# Why are some point groups for single atoms listed as Oh in the CCCBDB?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, symmetry, spectroscopy, databases, atomic-physics

Does anyone know why the CCCBDB database lists the tin cation and antimony atom as having the Oh point group (please see the screenshot below from CCCBDB when I look at "[All molecules sorted by Point Group](https://cccbdb.nist.gov/pglist.asp)")? Shouldn't the Oh point group be for symmetries of a regular tetrahedron?

Wouldn't it be more suitable to list Sn+ and Sb as Kh?

[image]

Comment: Kindly check if the electron density around the Sn$^+$ ion and Sb atom is spherically symmetric. I doubt if they are, especially considering the fact that relativistic effects are important to them.

Comment: It seems like Sb has 5 valence electrons and Sn is the next element in the periodic table so the Sn+ ion should have the same electronic configuration as Sb. Perhaps this is significant in some way?

Comment: On the topic of spherical symmetry, here is a related thread: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/610064/134583, although they're not talking about Sb or Sn+ specifically. As for the two species having the same electronic configurations: that could by why the point groups are the same, but it doesn't say why they are $O_h$.

Comment: [This says that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMpnK.png) the experimental point group for the Sn atom is $\textrm{K}_h$ but the theoretical point group at every level of theory and with every listed basis set, is $\textrm{O}_h$. For Sn+ and Sb, it's the same ($\textrm{K}_h$ experimental and $\textrm{O}_h$ for theory). There might be a typo. @HemanthHaridas is it common to look at the electron density when deciding a point group, or just the spatial arrangement of the nuclei?

Comment: If we are looking at just an atom or an ion, there is no spatial arrangement, it's just electron density, and I think that the experimental electron density is not spherically symmetric.

Comment: I got an answer to this question from Karl Irikura from NIST (the institute that hosts CCCBDB), and have asked him to write an answer for you.